# Highest point differential that has missed the playoffs(and vice versa)Nfl

Tags: american-football, nfl

What is the highest point differential that has missed the playoffs and what is the lowest point differential that has made the playoffs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2010 Seattle Seahawks are the [worst playoff team by point differential in NFL history](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-2010-seattle-seahawks-worst-playoff-team-ever/), making the playoffs by winning their division with a 7-9 record and a -97 point differential.

On the flip side, the [1991 San Francisco 49ers](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/sfo/1991.htm), in Steve Young's first season as a starter, outscored their opponents to the tune of 154 points (and this was in the 90s, so that was *huge* - 393 PF to 239 PA) - though much of that was scored in the final game, a [52-14 shellacking of the playoff-bound 11-5 Chicago Bears](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/199112230sfo.htm) who did not play their starters for large portions of the game.